# Python: Need to find such coefficients that multiplying them by known data points minimises SD

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a system of equations of the form

```
$n_i q=a_i \ 1\le i \le N$
```

where only `$a_i$` are known. I am trying to find the numbers `$n_i$` which should be close to small positive integers. I also know the bound for possible values of `$q$`. How do I solve such a system in Python?

Alternatively, we can say that I want to find such small positive integers that

`$SD(\frac{a_1}{n_1}, ...,\frac{a_i}{n_i},...,\frac{a_N}{n_N})$`
is minimized.

I thought about using `least squares` or `partial derivatives` and `Newton's method.` I'm not sure how to make curvefit work for $mx+b$ when I know that `$b=0$` but don't know any `$x$-s` except that they should be close to integers.

Comment: Too vague to be meaningfully actionable. "Close to small positive integers" - how close? how small? What are your values of a_i? What is a typical value of N?

Comment: What are the bounds on q?

Comment: @Reinderien , a_i are positive real numbers ranging from 5. ...  to 37. ... . q should be bigger than 0 but less than or equal to 5. ... . N is about a dozen.

Comment: @Reinderien ,  n_i - s should be no more than a few dozens. Ideally, about three fourths of them should should be less than a dozen.

Comment: @Reinderien , essentially what I'm trying to do is to analyze the results of Millikan's experiment where I am trying to figure out elementary charge by knowing it's approximate (because of errors) multiples derived in an experiment.

Comment: Can you post your actual experimental data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess at a solution with inline explanations and simulated data.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
from numpy.random import default_rng


'''
nq = a
"a" ranges between 5 and 37.
a_min, expected to be close to 5, will be scaled by 1/q to 1 <= n_min <= 12;
all other "a" will be scaled by the same q.

n will have the same distribution as "a".

To have 3/4 of the elements of n be 12 or less, either "a" has a uniform
distribution and q needs to take a fixed value:
(37 - 5)*0.75 + 5 = 29
q = 29/12 ~ 2.4

or the distribution of "a" needs to be made non-uniform; an exponential example:

n_min < 12 < n_max
5 < 12q < 37
0 < (12q - 5)/(37 - 5) < 1
0.75^p = (12q - 5)/(37 - 5)
p = log((12q - 5)/(37 - 5)) / log(0.75)

This all means problem bounds of

a_min a_max  n_min  n_max     q      p
    5    37  1.000  7.400 5.000
    5    37  1.622 12.000 3.083  0.000 (bad here and above)
    5    37  2.069 15.310 2.417  1.000
    5    37 10.000 74.000 0.500 12.047
    5    37 12.000 88.800 0.417    inf (bad here and below)
 
Regardless of the distribution of "a", for "n" to include 12 in its possible
range, 5/12 <= q <= 37/12 or 0.417 ~<= q ~<= 3.083.
'''

amin_theory = 5
amax_theory = 37
nmax_lower = 12          # Highest value of n for the lower 3/4 elements
nmin_upper = nmax_lower  # Lowest value of n for the highest element
nmax_upper_theory = amax_theory/amin_theory*nmax_lower  # Highest value of n for the highest element
qmin_theory = amin_theory/nmax_lower
qnom_theory = ((amax_theory - amin_theory)*0.75 + amin_theory)/nmax_lower
qmax_theory = amax_theory/nmax_lower


N = 14  # about a dozen
rand = default_rng(seed=0)
n_ideal = rand.integers(low=2, high=15, size=N)
n_noise = n_ideal + rand.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, size=N)
q_ideal = 2.4
a = n_noise*q_ideal
amin = a.min()
amax = a.max()
nmax_upper = amax/amin*nmax_lower
qmin = amin/nmax_lower
qmax = amax/nmax_lower

'''
Rounding produces sawtooth error which is impractical to optimize. A reasonable approximation is,
for the highest value whose relative quantization error is the lowest and sawtooth the highest-
frequency, try every integer in range, assuming that within the given integer the cost from
quantization error is differentiable.
'''
n_upper = np.arange(nmin_upper, 1 + np.round(nmax_upper))
n_upper_bounds = n_upper[:, np.newaxis] + ((-0.5, +0.5),)

# nq = a
q_init = amax / n_upper
q_bounds = (amax / n_upper_bounds)[:, ::-1]
n_rounded = np.round(a[:, np.newaxis] / q_init[np.newaxis, :])

# For each value of q, the error is the sum of squares of differences of n_rounded

def err(q: np.ndarray) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    n = a[:, np.newaxis] / q[np.newaxis, :]
    e = (n_rounded - n)**2
    return e, n

def errsum(q: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    e, n = err(q)
    return e.sum()

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    fun=errsum, x0=q_init, bounds=q_bounds,
)

q_opt = result.x
errs, n_opt = err(q_opt)
errs = errs.sum(axis=0)
order = np.argsort(errs)
q_opt = q_opt[order]
errs = errs[order]
n_opt = n_opt[:, order]
```